# Minecraft Frame Tearing

Tags: unity, gnome, minecraft, tearing

I've been trying to play Minecraft in Ubuntu. Under both the Unity and GNOME3 window managers, I notice serious frame tearing when in fullscreen mode. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide full details of your PC, but anyway..

If you are using an nVidia or AMD graphics card, you need to update the drivers and then do some tweaks in the CCSM (Compiz Config Settings Manager).

Check these links:

[[HOWTO] Optimize Minecraft for Linux](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/158692-howto-optimize-minecraft-for-linux/)

[Ubuntu12.04 & Up Video Tearing Fix (Nvidia)](http://www.awesomeonlinereviews.com/2012/08/ubuntuxubuntu-1204-video-tearing-fix.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.